# Applying the definition of $(a_n)$ tends to $+\infty$

Tags: sequences-and-series

A sequence $(a_n)$ tends to $+\infty$ iff given any number $C$ there's a number $N$ such that $n > N \implies a_n \ge C.$

I'd be interested to see how this definition can be applied to the two sequences below

$(a) \; 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, \ldots, n, 1, \ldots$

$(b) \; 2, 1, 4, 3, \ldots, 2n, 2n - 1,\ldots$

Thinking out loud: $n$ stands for index of a term. For $(b)$, let $C = 100000000000000000000000000$, but there's still some index $N$ among $n$ such that beyond the term indexed by $N$(the term $C$ occurs at this index or before it), all terms are greater than $C$. It's not true for $(a)$ because for any $C$ at index $N$, there's a term at index $N + k$ that equals $1$.

Do we think like that or how can I correct my thinking?

Comment: You might need to include language like "subsequence" in order to cover cases like you show.  Or else specify that sequences are monotone

Comment: For instance, in case (a), there exists a subsequence which tends to infinity.  But the sequence as a whole does not converge (diverges) since we have a subsequence with a finite limit and a separate subsequence with an infinite limit.

Comment: @ abiessu, thanks. I see. Both sequences contain subsequences without an upper bound, but in $(a)$ there's always a $1$ after any choice of $C$, right?

Comment: Correct.  The term "monotone subsequence" is also of value here.

Comment: You are correct; $(a)$ does not tend to infinity while $(b)$ does.

Comment: Basically, the definition is a way of formalizing the vague idea that $a_{\rm large~thing}=\rm large~thing$. This is true for $(b)$ but not $(a)$.